# soft debugger for microcontrollers

Tags: arm, microcontroller, pic

Are there any soft debuggers for microcontrollers (say PIC24) something like GDB. My platform doesn't run Linux so can’t use GDB. More than a debugger I need to log data, something like what CCP does.

I have a PICKit2 but it does not support runtime watch window update, only on breakpoints my watch variables be updated.

Has anyone tried using MODBUS RTU for runtime data logging ?

Comment: MODBUS is used for data acquisition in millions of devices each day...

Comment: You don't need Linux on the target system to use GDB, if your microcontroller supports hardware debugging over JTAG, SWD, or similar standard. Unfortunately, gdb has no support for PIC24, as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

Transmit your data over a serial bus and log it at the computer end. Many micros come with a UART so RS-232 messages could be logged by simply directing the serial input to a file (you might need a USB to serial converter, such as the FTDI devices/leads/cable assemblies based on them). Or use CAN bus or any [other serial protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_automation_protocols) that you can get an interface to your computer with, and possibly write your own logger.

Comment: Logging is not my problem, but it bloats the code. I want a smart logger that gives me only that I want. Can Calibration Protocol is a very good example. Another example is [µC/Prob](http://micrium.com/page/products/tools/probe) wondering how are they doing it..

Comment: μC/Probe also requires that you link your code with some 'µC/Probe-Target resident code', as the call it, so it's not "for free" in terms of code bloat. Alternatively, you can use JTAG, so in this case it's pretty much a debugger displaying variable values graphically.